# Insights last available data

Tags: facebook-insights

I'm trying to get the last value of the `page_fans_country` metric for a set of pages via fql in an efficient manner, so i have to specify in my query the exact `end_time` field to get for each page a single value (and save some bandwidth).

The problem is that some days of the week the right value of the `end_time` is `today - 3days` and other time it's `today - 4days`.

Is there a rule that Facebook follows to make these insights available across a week?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For this case, it's probably more efficient to get this via the Graph API than FQL:

```
/PAGE_ID/insights/page_fans_country?limit=1
```

This way you don't need to know the `end_time` like you do through FQL.

Comment: Thanks for response! i just tested it on the explorer and it returns two days : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=342030859226425%2Finsights%2Fpage_fans_country%3Flimit%3D1